# Elevation correction

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator, georeferencing, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

I have a digital elevation model produced from a drone survey via Drone Deploy. The file is a georeferenced TIFF.

The z values in the raster are relative to the survey only and not to actual ground level. So as an example, a z value of -39 on the raster is equivalent to 385m altitude in real life. 6.5 is 431m, -12 is 414m and so on. The difference is fairly consistent at 424 give or take.

I assume it would be a straight forward operation to apply a correction using the QGIS Raster Calculator.

What would the procedure be?

Comment: GDAL_Calc -A (your raster) -calc "A+424", from QGIS Raster Calculator  use (your raster)@1 + 424. How close do you need it to be? You say it's fairly much 424, is it close enough by just adding 424? It sounds like you're doing a geoid adjustment which wont be constant but may appear so if your area is small enough.

Comment: Thanks Michael. The area is fairly small - about 600m x 400m from memory. I haven't done a detailed analysis yet, but the few random selections that I have looked at show a difference of 424 +/- 2m.

Comment: Is +/- 2m close enough for your needs? With LiDAR I work to +/- 3mm using an ellipsoid to height datum surface, perhaps you could obtain a surface for your area then calculate your raster adjusted by the suface and see if it gets closer than 2m to your surveyed locations, though 424 metres is a very large separation, in Australia the separation is generally less than 50 metres. Where is your data captured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very simple procedure in the Raster Calculator:

Corrected elevation = Elevation Raster Layer + Difference.

Using above example:

Corrected elevation = Elevation Raster Layer + 424